# Ionic popup template content does not fix to popup window

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use a popup to view a list inside it. List contains many items. When i'm trying to do this, list is not fixing to popup menu in devices. It's working perfectly in browser. View in device looks like following image. [Mobile user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvhVW.jpg)

This is my controller

```
.controller('taskCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicPopup) {

$scope.tasksList = function () {
  $scope.listdata = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $scope.listdata.push(i)
  }
  var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: ' <style>.popup { width:500px; height:50%; }</style> <ion-list>                           ' +
    '  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in listdata"> ' +
    '    {{item.id}}                              ' +
    '  </ion-item>                             ' +
    '</ion-list>                               ',
    title: 'Current Tasks',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: '<b>Close</b>',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function (e) {
          myPopup.close();
        }
      },
    ]
  });
  myPopup.then(function (res) {
    console.log('Tapped!', res);
  });
};
})
```

Hope someone can figure it out the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem might be with `overflow` property of `.popup-body` class. Try adding below styles in template string or in your custom css file.

```
.platform-android .pop-up .popup-body{
    overflow : overlay;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. I add overflow attribute like following

 template: ' <style>.popup { width:500px; height:50%;overflow: overlay; }</style>